# Method 'Paste' of object'_Worksheet' Failed - how to resolve?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Runtime error 1004 Method Paste of object_worksheet failed being thrown in the below line. How to fix?

Posting full code below for additional context. I can get one image to move to the user selected cell, but error is thrown after the first iteration of the For loop @ the bottom.

```
Sub unload_word()
Dim wdApp As Object
Dim wdSH As InlineShape
Dim sCell As Range

On Error Resume Next
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application") 'get open word doc
On Error GoTo 0
If wdApp Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Word is not open."
    Exit Sub
End If

If wdApp.Documents(1).InlineShapes.count = 0 Then 'find images in word doc
    MsgBox "There are no images in this Word Doc."
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim shapecount As Integer 'counts # of images in the doc
shapecount = wdApp.Documents(1).InlineShapes.count
MsgBox "There are " & shapecount & " items in the selected document."

Dim wbOtherWB As Workbook
'checks to see if there's another excel book open, besides the one running the macro. other workbook will be the place where images are pasted
For Each wbOtherWB In Application.Workbooks
    If Not wbOtherWB Is ThisWorkbook Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next wbOtherWB
If wbOtherWB Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No other workbooks are open.", vbExclamation 'if theres not another workbook open then cancel the macro
    Exit Sub
End If
Dim usersheet As Worksheet
Set sCell = Application.InputBox("Select one cell", Type:=8) 'prompt user to choose a cell location
Set usersheet = ActiveSheet 'make user selected sheet a reference point for later
If sCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If sCell.Cells.count > 1 Then MsgBox "Pick one cell only"

For Each wdSH In wdApp.Documents(1).InlineShapes 
    wdApp.Documents(1).Activate 'activate word doc
    wdSH.Range.Copy 'copy image
    usersheet.Activate 'activate sheet where user chose cell
    usersheet.Paste Destination:=sCell 'paste in user cell. throws 1004 error
    Application.CutCopyMode = False 'clear clipboard
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
Dim usersheet As Worksheet
Set sCell = Application.InputBox("Select one cell", Type:=8) 'prompt user to choose a cell location
Set usersheet = ActiveSheet
If sCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If sCell.Cells.Count > 1 Then
  MsgBox "Pick one cell only"
  GoTo ErrExit
End If
For Each wdSH In wdApp.Documents(1).InlineShapes
    wdSH.Range.Copy
    usersheet.Paste Destination:=sCell
Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ErrExit:
wdApp.Quit
```

Without more of your code for context, though (especially relating to the instantiating of wdApp, the referenced document and wdSH), it's impossible to know what's going on elsewhere that might affect things.

Comment: Thanks macro for reviewing. Unfortunately error still persists even when trying the above suggestion, 1004 error throws on the usersheet.Paste line.

Updated the post to reflect the entirety of the sub for additional context.

Comment: You updated code, as posted, runs fine if 'Dim wdSH As InlineShape' is changed to 'Dim wdSH As Object' - which is what it should be for the late binding you're using. All inlineshapes copied from Word get pasted onto the same Excel cell.

Comment: I updated wdSH to As Object - 1004 error still throws on the same line. I get two images to paste to the user cell before the error. Any thoughts for why this happens?

Comment: Maybe you have a faulty Office installation. Try repairing it.

Comment: I moved the above code into a different module to separate from other macros in that module. It no longer throws the error! But, still only pastes two screenshots from the Word doc, despite the For loop running on for each item. Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure: (a) the pasted images aren't being hidden because they're pasted on top of each other; and (b) the images in the Word document are all formatted as in-line with the text? When I run the macro multiple inline images are pasted on top of each other - the code doesn't stop at 2.

Comment: After pasting the image, I used the below to space the images:

   `usersheet.Paste Destination:=sCell
    Set sCell = sCell.Offset(0, 10)`

I also checked manually in the word doc to confirm all images are formatted as in-line. Additionally - I did run Office repair, no change at this time.

Comment: As I said, even without any of the fairly obvious improvements I posted, your code works just fine for me.